# convert pandas column to to_datetime

Tags: pandas, string-to-datetime

I am trying to convert 'Thursday - 6/13/2019' to pd.to_datetime in a pandas dataframe column called 'timestamp".

Here is my attempt to solve the problem:

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%A - %x')

Thanks.

Comment: Solved it... pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.split(' - ').str[1])

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about **%m/%d/%Y** instead of **%x**

```
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%A - %m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Hi, this is the response: ValueError: time data 'Totals' does not match format '%A - %m/%d/%Y' (match)

Comment: How about `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].astype(str), format='%A - %m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: Is there any other value which is not the day of the week?

Comment: Same error - ValueError: time data 'Totals' does not match format '%A - %m/%d/%Y' (match) using df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].astype(str), format='%A - %m/%d/%Y')

Comment: This works... df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.split(' - ').str[1]) Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Sorry  to late. Good job great:)